# allow sudo user to execute multiple commands for only ONE file

Tags: linux, command-line, sudoers

I'm trying to allow only one user to be able to use only 'cat,head,tail' on some of the log files. What is the exact syntax to use here. I tried

```
user   ALL  /bin/cat  /var/log/maillog
```

Which works great, but I also need to give the user the head and tail commands. I tried grouping those commands under:

```
Cmnd_Alias VIEW = /bin/cat, /usr/bin/head, /usr/bin/tail
```

Now I try and add this VIEW alias but I'm not sure where it should go as I've tried many different ways. Basically the conclusion is that I may be able to use this Cmnd_Alias but I am not able to specify the file name /var/log/maillog with that. Can anyone help with the proper syntax please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this works or me:

```
Cmnd_Alias VIEW = /bin/cat /var/log/messages, /bin/head /var/log/messages, /bin/tail /var/log/messages, /bin/tailf /var/log/messages
luser ALL=NOPASSWD: VIEW
```

or

```
luser ALL=VIEW
```